# Dynamically add to HTML list from Rails hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-lists

I have a hash with many values. For each of the values I want to generate a list entry.
When I do the following, only the last entry from the hash is displayed.

```
<% data.each do |k, v| %>
    <li><%= v['name'] %> - <%= v['email'] %></li>
<% end %>
```

`data` is loaded from a YAML

```
person:
   name: ABC
   email: xyz@gmail.com
person:
   name: LMN
   email: qrs@yahoo.com
```

How do I add all the values from hash in a html list?
Thanks

Comment: The only thing that looks fishy is your variable called `Config`. This shows up on most lists of Rails' reserved words, so it's probably a good idea to name your variable something else (use lowercase letters, also).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's your actual YAML file, the the reason you are only seeing one object is because your keys are all `person`. If you parse this into a hash, each instance of `person` is going to be stored on the `person` key, and since hash keys must be unique, only the last record is persisted.

You probably want to structure this as an array of hashes (or "sequence of mappings" in YAML speak):

```
---
- name: LMN
  email: qrs@yahoo.com
- name: ABC
  email: xyz@gmail.com
```

Then iterate as:

```
<% data.each do |entry| %>
  <li><%= entry['name'] %> - <%= entry['email'] %></li>
<% end %>
```